# How to extract text from docx files with android

Tags: android, apache-poi, docx

I have tried alot to solve the problem I am getting while using apache poi, but getting errors, each time. Is there any other way to extract text from .docx files or can we able to use javax package in android.

Thanks.

Comment: What errors are you getting ?

Comment: I am getting following errors : Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring

Comment: When I tried to solve this issue I am getting XMLFactoryEvent Class not found exception.

Answer (score 1):

I have found way to extract text from .docx. I have used zipextractor for this